# How to create Tooltips like MS Office 2007/2010 in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, tooltip, ribbon

How can I create complex ToolTips for my WPF RibbonItems like I have seen in MS-Office 2007/2010. A Sample image is given below.

[image]

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx) I got an image just like that but MSDN does not tell us how we can create it.

[image]

If anyone can help me in making Tooltip like MS Office I will appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just throw a grid into the tooltip's content and add a `LinearGradientBrush` to the background?

Comment: @CarsonMyers: I know that inside Tooltip i can put any controls that i want (Grid, Buttons, Images etc.). But how to use `ToolTipImageSource`, `ToolTipTitle`, `ToolTipDescription`...? Are these controls or is this MSDN way of just explaining those things?

Comment: If I am not wrong in the link you provided, There are installation & documentation on ribbon in WPF. Isn't it helpful?

Comment: @uDaY: Yeah it is helpful in explaining features of Ribbon but not helpful in how to create them.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, theres a sample code, see my answer. Might be helpful in demystifying things & Customize if at your will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonbutton.aspx) there are several properties on a `RibbonButton` that refer to parts of the enhanced tooltip:

- [ToolTipDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonbutton.tooltipdescription.aspx)
- [ToolTipFooterDescription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonbutton.tooltipfooterdescription.aspx)
- [ToolTipFooterImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonbutton.tooltipfooterimagesource.aspx)
- [ToolTipFooterTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonbutton.tooltipfootertitle.aspx)
- [ToolTipImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonbutton.tooltipimagesource.aspx)
- [ToolTipTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonbutton.tooltiptitle.aspx)

Come to think of it, those are the *exact* properties mentioned in the screenshot you have there.

Answer (score 2):

You can download [`Ribbon Sample`](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9620) code.

If you are beginner start with this very comprehensive tutorial [Creating a Ribbon Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316924%28v=vs.85%29)

[Specifying Ribbon Image resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316921%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Also I would recommend to read this: [Understanding Commands & Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd316916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For more specific issues you can find quick help in [`MSDN Ribbon Forum`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsribbondevelopment)

Hope it helps!